# importing excel file in php

Tags: php, excel

friends i already know how to upload .csv file format through php.
but now i need to know how to upload .xls file in php.
i tried of this code but it doesn't work properly.. can any one able to give suggestion for me??

```
if ($_POST['frmSubmit']) {
    $file = $_FILES['frmUpload']['name'];   

    if ($file) {
        $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
        $data->read('name'.$file);

        for ($k = 1; $k < count($strDatas->sheets[0]['numRows']); $k++) {       
            $name = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$k][1];
            $code = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$k][2];
            $email = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$k][3];
            $designation = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$k][4];
            $number = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$k][5];
            $salary = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$k][6]; 
            $age = $data->sheets[0]['cells'][$k][7];    

            doInsertEmployeeDetails($name, $code, $email, $designation, $number, $salary, $age);
        }   
    } else {
        $strMessage = 'Please upload a valid file.';                                                                    
        $strClass = 'Error';
    }
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work, what error occurs?  Are you using a spreadsheet library like Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader() ?

Comment: nopes i dont know about library.. can u explain about it please?? #drmarvelous

Comment: My suspicion is you googled that code and unfortunately don't understand what it is doing.  Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader() is not a standard PHP function, and is instead likely part of a library.  You may have luck using PHPExcel for this purpose.

Comment: thanks brother,, how to use PHPExcel rather than Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader() ??  #drmarvelous

Comment: You should review the code examples from PHPExcel, we are not able to write your code for you.

Comment: okay brother,, thanks for ur work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file upload is a file upload. Doesn't matter if it's .txt, .jpg, .exe, or .foobarbaz. PHP doesn't care.

What you ARE doing wrong is making up a totally fake name for that file and somehow expecting PHP to magically fix that.

You need to first confirm that an upload actually occurred and **SUCCEEDED**

```
if ($_FILES['frmUpload']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   die("File upload failed with error code #" . $_FILES['frmUpload']['error']);
}
```

Then just use the standard temp filename that PHP assigns, not the utterly meaning filename that existed on the client:

```
$data->read($_FILES['frmUpload']['tmp_name']);
```

And of course, you should probably check if that upload really is an excel file, and not something completely different.

Comment: got no error brother..Array
(
    [frmUpload] => Array
        (
            [name] => Book1.xls
            [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/php9rxzFD
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 8837
        )

)